# Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.lang.Object)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, jpa-2.1

I already went through the below few links, but it did not solved my problem:

1. [Java Jackson: deserialize complex polymorphic object model: JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833979/java-jackson-deserialize-complex-polymorphic-object-model-jsonmappingexception)
2. [Java Jackson - Unexpected token (START_ARRAY), expected VALUE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923809/java-jackson-unexpected-token-start-array-expected-value-string)

In my project, we've 15 batch jobs. I am converting 15 batch jobs into 15 different micro-services. For that I have created one Spring Boot module, which has Entity classes, JPA repository layer and service layer. That jar I will import into each micro-services (batch jobs), so that batch job should work fine.

I am using Spring boot + Spring Batch - XML based approach.

so I have XJPA module ready and imported into another Spring Boot module where I have written XML based batch job configurations.

code:

```
@Component
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ImportResource("classpath:jobs/ABC_context.xml")
public class XXXLauncher {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    public void executeXXXXXXXXXXJob() {

        try {
            // @formatter:off
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("runMode", "XXXX")
                    .addDate("date", new Date())
                    .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
            // @formatter:on

            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**ABC_job.xml**

```
<batch:job id="x">
    <batch:step id="y">
        <batch:tasklet ref="xyzTasklet" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="stepScope" class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
    <property name="autoProxy" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xyzTasklet" class="com.XXXX.tasklet.xyzTasklet" scope="step">
    <property name="runType" value="#{jobParameters['runMode']}" />
    <property name="executionContext" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}" />
</bean>
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:309) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparXXtatement(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:756) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:112) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutionDependencies(SimpleJobExplorer.java:202) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutions(SimpleJobExplorer.java:83) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.getJobExecutions(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder.getNextJobParameters(JobParametersBuilder.java:264) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:162) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:179) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:134) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:128) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.lang.Object)
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["map"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1498) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportWrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1273) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._locateTypeId(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:96) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:712) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:529) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3077) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:70) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:50) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:322) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Another error: Now I am getting

> Field job in required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' that could not be found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration to Spring Boot 2 and using Spring Batch 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625231/migration-to-spring-boot-2-and-using-spring-batch-4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once I removed the line

```
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping();
```

It solved my problem. But be careful, in some other cases this line is needed

Comment: this should be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by using the toList() call method in StreamApi.

```
return collection.stream().map(row -> ItemGroupPathDto.builder()
                .id(UUID.fromString((String) row[0]))
                .name((String) row[1])
                .shortName((String) row[2])
                .build())
        .toList(); //change this to .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When you call toList() and then serialize the object, the collection type simply disappears. Jackson expects to see a string (VALUE STRING) with a collection type, but receives the beginning of an object (OBJECT_VALUE)